# Communication with the deployer was lost during the deployment

Tags: tfs, msbuild, release-management, devops, ms-release-management

I am using MS Release management with agent based release templates for my releases.

The releases are getting failed with the following error message and which is randomly happening for different actions in the deployment sequence.

"Communication with the deployer was lost during the deployment. Please make sure (1) the deployer machine has not rebooted during installation and (2) the component timeout is sufficient to copy the files from the drop location to the deployer machine and install the package."

Please note:

1) Deployer machine was not rebooted during the deployment

2) I have created custom components for all actions and made the components' time out to 60 mins

When I restarts the release, it succeeded with out any error. What could be the reason of this error, what is the solution.

Experts please share your views on this.

Comment: Could you share some  logs when you got the fail info. If it's a randomly issue.  Did you find a stable way to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Nowadays, most of the times I goes for "Retry Failed Deployment" to restart 'deploy' step, which had got 'rejected'  due to this error. The message I mentioned in the question was the exact message from the deployment log.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have a Encrypted field in your deployment component, just re-enter the value for that encrypted field.

You could refer to this: https://lajak.wordpress.com/2015/12/14/release-management-communication-with-the-deployer-was-lost-during-the-deployment-the-parameter-is-incorrect/

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.